# Symfony: how to sort One2Many/Many2One of an entity?

Tags: php, symfony, sorting, orm, doctrine-orm

I've three entities: `Product`, `ProductPicture` and `Picture`.

I'd like to sort the pictures by it's position and tried [this](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/ordered-associations.html), code below.

**Result**: it's not sorting the joined pictures by position. It's sorting the products by the pictures' position.

I'm confused. As far as I can see, I followed the docs, but get a weird result. Cache was cleared.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Entity: **Product**

```
// ...
class Product {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductPicture", mappedBy="product")
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"position" = "DESC"})    // <------ !!!
     */
    protected $pictures;

    // ...
}
```

Entity: **ProductPicture**

```
// ...
class ProductPicture {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $position;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="pictures")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $product;


    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Picture")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="picture_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $picture;

    // ...
}
```

Entity: **Picture**

```
// ...
class Picture {
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="path", type="string")
     */
    protected $path;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: How are you retrieving the pictures? Are you doing `$product->getPictures()->getPicture()->getPath()`? If its sorting the products by the picture position then what query are you performing that exhibits this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/ordered-associations.html) are right:

```
<?php
/** @Entity **/
class User
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group")
     * @OrderBy({"name" = "ASC"})
     **/
    private $groups;
}
```

In my case the `findAll()`-method of the `repository` was overwritten which led to this mess. Make sure, your customized queries are not in conflict with the doctrine defaults, if you've the same issue. :-)